# Why should we use anonymous functions with jQuery instead of the function directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some jQuery methods expect a function as a parameter, but to work they should receive an anonymous function as a parameter rather than a function directly, as in the following example:

```
$("a").on("click", function () { retornaNada(); });
```

rather than

```
 $("a").on("click", retornaNada());
```

Consider `retornaNada()` as a function without any body of code. Why can not we pass the function directly?

Comment: You need to pass them a reference to a function, not an *"inner function"*. So, you'd do `.on("click", retornaNada);`.

Comment: not sure why the down votes... this person clearly is new to javascript and doesn't understand the way it works

Comment: The one that downvoted could, please, tell why?

Comment: Also, some functions require access to parameters in the scope they were created, so closures are used: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/

Comment: The code examples are both hideously broken with mismatched parenthesis, stray periods and apostrophes.

Comment: @Quentin, I don't know what happend, I think when moderation edited my question I was editing too and the question got wrong.

Comment: @Sam I'll read the link you provided, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working but you need to pass only the function reference (name) like this :

```
function test (e) {
    console.log('test ok');
}
$('body').on('click', test);
```

Comment: Change this to say *"pass a reference to a function"* rather than *"pass only the function name"*. What you said it true, but it's not complete.

Comment: *name* isn't always the reference. `function (e) { // }` is also a reference that isn't passed by name. That's the point I was trying to get across.

Comment: Another way to say this is "pass the function, not the result."  Unless the function result is itself a function, of course.

Comment: Obviously the guy is a new to JS, it's more clear to him explained in less technical terms. If it's a reference, closure, or who cares what else he really won't care until he understands the basics of the error..

Comment: @Goran.it You should always give a complete example, that introduces the OP to technical terminology. *This isn't an attack on your answer. It's a plead to improve it.* Mention that referring to the function by name is one form of referencing the function. Then, show him that it is equivalent to passing an anonymous function, which is also a function reference.

Comment: I got it now. I either code a anonymous function or call the reference for a already implemented one.

Comment: @crush, I understand the anonymous function concept, it's the same that we use in Java when we use anonymous functions.