# How to pass parameters in function calls by reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently asked the question, **[Why should we use anonymous functions with jQuery instead of the function directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531989/why-should-we-use-anonymous-functions-with-jquery-instead-of-the-function-direct)** and along with the accepted answer came a second question: How to pass arguments to one JS function that we are invoking by reference?

How would be the call to $("a").on("click", retornaNada); whether this function receives a simple parameters such as a number or as a more complex object?

Comment: the arguments passed to retornaNada are set by $.on(), so it will be the same pattern each invocation. you can define extra params and curry the first ones using Function.bind().

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: It is now, thanks for remembering, @Jack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your actual example:

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada);
```

If you read the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it will tell you what it will pass to the handler. It will call whatever function you provide and pass it an `eventObject` which has various properties (see the docs). If you want, you can pass more data as part of your binding that will end up in `event.data` (see the section *Passing data to the handler*)

So if you do:

```
$("a").on("click", { foo:"bar" }, retornaNada);
```

and have a function `retornaNada`:

```
function retornaNada(e) {
    console.log(e.data.foo);     // logs "bar"
}
```

Alternatively, if you want more control over what gets passed to your function, this would be a good place to use those anonymous functions:

```
$("a").on("click", function() { 
    retornaNada(myOwn, argumentsTo, myFunction); 
});
```

So, for example, if `retornaNada` looked like this:

```
function retornaNada(anumber) {

}
```

You could then do:

```
$("a").on("click", function() { 
    retornaNada(1); 
});
```

**Edit**: Some thoughts on the first option (using `data`) and the second (wrapping with an anonymous function).

Let's say you have a function called `addToTotal` that is going to increase a counter every time an event happened. With the first option, your function might look like this:

```
function addToTotal(e) {
    theTotal += e.data.amountToAdd;
}
```

This is fine, of course, but what if you also have other logic elsewhere that you need to increase your total? You need to either reproduce the logic of the body of your function (either inline or in another function), or you need to "fake" and event object

```
addToTotal({ data: 1 });     // fake event object - this is kind of stupid
```

In addition, a function `addToTotal` that takes an argument that isn't actually the amount you want to add is goofy and will likely confuse anybody else looking at your code.

In that case, it would be a lot better to define `addToTotal` more sensibly to take a number and *add it to the total*:

```
function addToTotal(number) {
    theTotal += number;
}
```

Now I can call it anywhere:

```
addToTotal(1);     // this looks a lot better!
```

but I can't use it as an event handler because it will pass an `eventObject` instead of the number I need so this:

```
$("a").on("click", addToTotal)
```

Isn't going to work. So instead, we can wrap our function in an annoymous function:

```
$("a").on("click", function() { addToTotal(1); } )
```

And now we have an event that will call our function, *and* our function doesn't look goofy and can be completely agnostic about whether it's called from an event handler or called somewhere else.

Of course, if you really wanted to, you could do this:

```
function addToTotalEventHandler(e) {
    addToTotal(e.data.amountToAdd);
}
```

And then:

```
$("a").on("click", { data : 1 }, addToTotalEventHandler);
```

But that is basically the same as the anonymous wrapper, but you've had to create a new function just for this single use.

Comment: I didn't understand the alternative, could explain more? And what are those `myOwn, argumentsTo, myFunction` parameters?

Comment: @Philippe: They are whatever you want them to be. What arguments does your function `retornaNada` actually take? I edited a little to (hopefully) make that clearer.

Comment: OK, now I get it, this way is how almost everybody does, i wanted to know only for knowing the syntax purpose how we do it without a anonymous function and you showed in the first example. I just dind't got why we have more control in the second alternative than in the first.

Comment: @Philippe: In the first example, your function must be expecting an `eventObject` as an argument. This is fine, if handling events is all this function is going to do, but can be a problem if you want you function to be called from other places. The second option, where you wrap your function in an anonymous function, allows you to have `retornaNada` take whatever arguments you want without worrying about how it was called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, yours is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `$("a").on("click", retornaNada)` the given function is called like:

```
retornaNada.call(<anchor-object>, <event-data>)
```

Whereby `<anchor-object>` is the DOM object of the anchor that's clicked, available to your function as `this`, and `<event-data>` is a wrapper object for the click event itself, so:

```
function retornaNada(e)
{
    console.log(this); // DOM object
    console.log(e); // event object
}
```

If your function does not expect an event object as its first argument, the typical thing to do is use a wrapper function, i.e.:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    retornaNada(... whatever ...);
});
```

Comment: But what if `retornaNada()` has now parameters and becomes `retornaNada(number)`?

Comment: If your function does not expect an event object as its first parameter you need a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
var foo = function () {
  console.log(arguments);
};
```

We can invoke it as:

```
foo(1,2,3,4);                  //[1,2,3,4]
foo.apply(window, [1,2,3,4]);  //[1,2,3,4]
foo.call(window, 1,2,3,4);     //[1,2,3,4]
```

We can pass `foo` to another function and invoke it the same way:

```
function bar() {
  foo(1,2,3,4);                  //[1,2,3,4]
  foo.apply(window, [1,2,3,4]);  //[1,2,3,4]
  foo.call(window, 1,2,3,4);     //[1,2,3,4]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be `var foo = function(arguments) { console.log(arguments); };`, otherwise how would console.log know what is arguments?

Comment: Each function has variable called `arguments` inside its body. @Philippe checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: "arguments" is predefined inside all JS functions.

Comment: @Philippe: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: One more information that I didn't know. Great answer!

Comment: @MinkoGechev how would I invoke `foo` in a `$("a").on("click", foo)` call and pass those arguments, that's my real doubt?

Comment: You want to invoke `foo` and pass the returned result to $('a').on('click',...) or?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Function Prototype Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Basicly, it rebind the arguments of the function reference. But you lose the reference to this (which is the same of `event.currentTarget`).

You would use it like this :

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada.bind('something that will equal this', 'arg1', 1));
```

And the function receive :

```
function retornaNada(a, b, c){
    console.log(this); //'something that will equal this'
    console.log(a); //'arg1'
    console.log(b); // 1
    console.log(c); // Event object
}
```

Using bind, the first passed argument will be the `this` reference and following argument will be arguments in function.

The original arguments (in this case `Event`) will always be the last one.

Comment: So in your example `this` would be `a` and the argument passed as 1 has no purpose at all, right?

Comment: @Philippe those are random values. In this case, `this` is a string containing `something that will equal this` (the first argument when calling `.bind()`) and `a` is a string `arg1` since it is the second argument in bind. But no argument have a purpose in this example...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand in my first reading, now I get it.